# Issue subtracting days from calendar

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

I have an horizontal calendar in my application. So I have implemented the following library https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar
I also have implemented my own back and forward button.

Pressing back takes back one day from current date and forward takes one day forward. Suppose today is 10th August and I scrolled horizontally till 15th July without pressing back or forward button. Now if I press back button instead of going to 14th July, I go back to 9th August.

Following is my code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.myapplication.HorizontalCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:selectedDateBackground="@drawable/selected_date"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/calendarView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Forward"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/calendarView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kotlin code:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var counter: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2)

    val format1 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)
    val currentDate = format1.format(Calendar.getInstance().time)

    Toast.makeText(this,currentDate.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    val startDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -10)


    val endDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 30)

    val horizontalCalendar = HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView)
            .range(startDate, endDate)
            .datesNumberOnScreen(7)
            .build()


    horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(object : HorizontalCalendarListener() {
        override fun onDateSelected(date: Calendar, position: Int) {
            val selectedDate = format1.format(date.time)

            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    "Pritish"+SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.US).format(date.time),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            if(format1.parse(selectedDate).before(format1.parse(currentDate))){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Cannot selecte previous date",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                        selectedDate
                        ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onCalendarScroll(calendarView: HorizontalCalendarView,
                                      dx: Int, dy: Int) {


            Log.i("Pritish",dx.toString()+dy.toString())


            counter += if(dx<0){
                -1
            } else {
                1
            }

        }

        override fun onDateLongClicked(date: Calendar, position: Int): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    })

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

    back.setOnClickListener {

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,counter-1)
        counter = 0
        horizontalCalendar.selectDate(cal,false)
        horizontalCalendar.refresh()

    }

    forward.setOnClickListener {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,counter+1)
        counter = 0
        horizontalCalendar.selectDate(cal,false)
        horizontalCalendar.refresh()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: calendar does not recognize that you are in july 15th. So create an instance and store the new value and then use that value while using back or forward.

Comment: @sanjeev i did what you said but i am getting illegal arguments at cal.add(cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),-1)

Comment: set the selected date to the place Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH. That is cal.add(selecteddate,-1)

Comment: Is counter getting set to the correct value? What does the logging show you? You might as well log the counter in the click listeners as well.  Does `onDateSelected` get triggered during scrolling or only if they tap on a date?

Comment: counter gets incement or decreemented multiple times even if i swipe a single date

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible that `onDateSelected` will get fired during scroll and that you can use that plus a simple +1/-1, but you'll have to try that to see if it works -- it's hard to validate just based on looking at the code for the library.

Comment: I did what you said, though the error is gone but the behaviour is not correct

Comment: Well, progress -- did you change the second parameter?  What is happening now instead?

Comment: I updated the code according to bernlim answer but still it does not works.

Comment: @Geoffrey, for future reference: if you are certain a question has been changed so substantively that it invalidates existing answers, you may roll it back to a prior state if you wish. We're very keen on discouraging time-wasting questions here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution with the code you have provided. Try keeping a global counter of the number of swipes (-1 for a back swipe and +1 for a forward swipe). Every time a swipe event happens, update that counter.

Then, in your back and forward listeners, utilize that counter. For example, if you had swiped back 5 days, `COUNTER = -5`. Then if the user clicks the back button,

`cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (COUNTER-1))`

Remember to reset your counter to 0 every time after a button click.

To combine that with `onCalendarScroll`, you can set another global variable that tracks the total dx change. When the dx hits a certain value, you know that a full swipe has been made, so the counter +/- 1. Here's some code to illustrate:

```
private var dx_tracker: Int = 0
private var counter: Int = 0
private SWIPE_VAL = <your tested value>

override fun onCalendarScroll(calendarView: HorizontalCalendarView,
                                  dx: Int, dy: Int) {
    Log.i("Pritish", dx.toString() + dy.toString())
    dx_tracker += dx

    if(dx_tracker >= SWIPE_VAL) {
        counter += 1;
        dx_tracker = 0;
    }
    else if(dx_tracker <= -SWIPE_VAL) {
        counter -= 1;
        dx_tracker = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah you're using a library from someone else. have you tried using the 'onCalendarScroll' listener mentioned on that library's README?

Comment: yes i am using that but dont know how to check for directions. I am checking dx and dy values, scrolling just once, increases or decreases the counter value many times

Comment: what if the user scrolls rapidly then too the counter will decrement once and not by the number of dates scrolled by the user

Comment: Maybe when dx changes by a certain amount then that will count as "one swipe" or "one date decrement". That is something you will have to test out. But I think with some refining, this idea will work.

Comment: could you update your original post with the new code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177987/discussion-between-bernlim-and-nudge).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set date in **cal** instance.

I didn't find any syntax which set **cal** instance.

you have defined cal instance like this

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
```

Your counter is not increasing. So, it will take you to previous date. **cal** always stores 10th August, If you have not pressed any buttons.

You can reset **cal** instance **onDateSelected** method